# Building a 12 hour Clock

Tags: java, constructor, clock

I am currently attempting to build a data type Time() that interacts with input from a main class, to create a time on a 12 hour clock (e.g. the input (16, 47), would give you 4:47 PM) The methods can make adjustments to the inputted data that would normally be consider invalid to make it accurate again (e.g the input value for (28, -148) would remove 2 hours and 28 minutes from the hour 28 evaluating to (25, 32) and the 25 would evaluate to 1, giving a time of 1:32 AM). I'm getting the wrong values from what I've created so far, based on this driver program.

```
package newProject;

/**
 * A program to test the Time class.
 *
 * 
 */
public class TestTime {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Basic Times\n"
                    +  "-----------");
    testTime(12, 30, 12, 30, "12:30 PM");
    testTime(16, 16, "4:00 PM");
    testTime(0, 0, 0, 0, "12:00 AM");
    testTime(0, 10, 0, 10, "12:10 AM");
    testTime(1, 5, 1, 5, "1:05 AM");
    testTime(11, 59, 11, 59, "11:59 AM");
    testTime(12, 12, "12:00 PM");
    testTime(12,1,12,1, "12:01 PM");
    testTime(13,55,13,55, "1:55 PM");
    testTime(23,55,23,55, "11:55 PM");
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Invalid Times\n"
                    +  "-------------");
    testTime(24, 0, "12:00 AM");
    testTime(49, 10, 1, 10, "1:10 AM");
    testTime(49, 125, 3, 5, "3:05 AM");
    testTime(-1, 23, "11:00 PM");
    testTime(0, -1, 23, 59, "11:59 PM");
    testTime(-27, 21, "9:00 PM");
    testTime(10, -125, 7, 55, "7:55 AM");
    testTime(-55, -308, 11, 52, "11:52 AM");
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("addMinutes\n"
                    +  "----------");
    testAdd(0, 0, 20, 0, 20, "12:20 AM");
    testAdd(0, 0, 90, 1, 30, "1:30 AM");
    testAdd(0, 40, 30, 1, 10, "1:10 AM");
    testAdd(0, 40, 90, 2, 10, "2:10 AM");
    testAdd(23, 50, 11, 0, 1, "12:01 AM");
    testAdd(23, 50, 3 * 24 * 60 + 1, 23, 51, "11:51 PM");
    System.out.println();
}

/**
 * Test whether Time constructor, getters, and print 
 * are behaving properly when zero minutes.
 * 
 * @param hrs       what hour to say to the constructor
 * @param finalHrs  what hour the Time should end up with
 * @param rep       how that Time should print out
 */
private static void testTime(int hrs,
                             int finalHrs,
                             String rep) {
    System.out.print("new Time(" + hrs + ", 0) --> " + finalHrs + ", 0: ");

    Time t = new Time(hrs, 0);
    if (t.getHour() == finalHrs && t.getMinute() == 0)
        System.out.println("PASS");
    else
        System.out.println("FAIL");
    t.print();
    System.out.println(" should be " + rep);
}

/**
 * Test whether Time constructor, getters, and print are
 * behaving properly when minutes are not (necessarily) 0.
 * 
 * @param hrs           what hour to give the constructor
 * @param mins          what minute to give the constructor
 * @param finalHrs      what hour the Time should end up with
 * @param finalMins     what minute the Time should end up with
 * @param rep           how the Time should print out
 */
private static void testTime(int hrs, int mins,
                             int finalHrs, int finalMins,
                             String rep) {
    System.out.print("new Time(" + hrs + ", " + mins + ") --> "
        + finalHrs + ", " + finalMins + ": ");

    Time t = new Time(hrs, mins);
    if (t.getHour() == finalHrs && t.getMinute() == finalMins)
        System.out.println("PASS");
    else
        System.out.println("FAIL");
    t.print();
    System.out.println(" should be " + rep);
}

/**
 * Check whether addMinutes, getters, and print are working properly.
 * @param hrs           what hour to give the constructor
 * @param mins          what minute to give the constructor
 * @param addMins       the number of minutes to add to the Time
 * @param finalHrs      what hour the Time should end up with
 * @param finalMins     what minute the Time should end up with
 * @param rep           how the (later) Time should print out
 */
private static void testAdd(int hrs, int mins, int addMins,
                            int finalHrs, int finalMins,
                            String rep) {
    Time t = new Time(hrs, mins);
    Time t2 = t.addMinutes(addMins);

    System.out.print("Adding " + addMins + " minutes to ");
    t.print();
    System.out.print(" --> ");
    if (t2.getHour() == finalHrs && t2.getMinute() == finalMins)
        System.out.println("PASS");
    else
        System.out.println("FAIL");
    t2.print();
    System.out.println(" should be " + rep);
}
```

}

So far this is what I've put together for the methods required to modify these, but I don't really know where to go next.

```
package newProject;


public class Time {

    private final int MAX_HOURS = 23;
    private final int MIN_HOURS = 0;
    private final int MAX_MINUTES = 59;
    private final int MIN_MINUTES = 0;
    private int hour;
    private int minute;

    private Time() {

    }

    public Time(int hrs, int mins) {
        this.hour = hrs;
        this.minute = mins;

    }

    private void fixMe() {
        if (minute > MAX_MINUTES) {
            this.minute %= minute/60; 
            this.hour = minute/60 + hour;
        } 
        if (minute < MIN_MINUTES) {
            this.minute = minute + 60;
        }
        if (hour > MAX_HOURS) {
            this.hour %= hour/24; 
        } 
        if(hour < MIN_HOURS) {
            this.hour = hour + 24;
        }

    }

    public int getHour() {
        return this.hour;
    }

    public int getMinute() {
        return this.minute;
    }

    public Time addMinutes(int mins) {
        Time t = new Time();
        t.fixMe();
        return t;

    }

    public void print() {

        if (hour == 0) {
            hour = 12;
        }
        if (hour > 1 && hour <= 12) {
            System.out.print(hour);
        } else {
            System.out.print(hour - 12);
        }
        if (minute < 10) {
            System.out.print(":0" + minute);
        } else {
            System.out.print(minute);
        }
        if (hour <= 11) {
            System.out.print(" AM");
        } else 
            System.out.print(" PM");
    }

}
```

These are the outputs that I am getting, which are far from what I am looking for.

```
    run:
Basic Times
-----------
new Time(12, 30) --> 12, 30: PASS
1230 PM should be 12:30 PM
new Time(16, 0) --> 16, 0: PASS
4:00 PM should be 4:00 PM
new Time(0, 0) --> 0, 0: PASS
12:00 PM should be 12:00 AM
new Time(0, 10) --> 0, 10: PASS
1210 PM should be 12:10 AM
new Time(1, 5) --> 1, 5: PASS
-11:05 AM should be 1:05 AM
new Time(11, 59) --> 11, 59: PASS
1159 AM should be 11:59 AM
new Time(12, 0) --> 12, 0: PASS
12:00 PM should be 12:00 PM
new Time(12, 1) --> 12, 1: PASS
12:01 PM should be 12:01 PM
new Time(13, 55) --> 13, 55: PASS
155 PM should be 1:55 PM
new Time(23, 55) --> 23, 55: PASS
1155 PM should be 11:55 PM

Invalid Times 
-------------
new Time(24, 0) --> 0, 0: FAIL
12:00 PM should be 12:00 AM
new Time(49, 10) --> 1, 10: FAIL
3710 PM should be 1:10 AM
new Time(49, 125) --> 3, 5: FAIL
37125 PM should be 3:05 AM
new Time(-1, 0) --> 23, 0: FAIL
-13:00 AM should be 11:00 PM
new Time(0, -1) --> 23, 59: FAIL
12:0-1 PM should be 11:59 PM
new Time(-27, 0) --> 21, 0: FAIL
-39:00 AM should be 9:00 PM
new Time(10, -125) --> 7, 55: FAIL
10:0-125 AM should be 7:55 AM
new Time(-55, -308) --> 11, 52: FAIL
-67:0-308 AM should be 11:52 AM

addMinutes
----------
Adding 20 minutes to 12:00 PM --> FAIL
12:00 PM should be 12:20 AM
Adding 90 minutes to 12:00 PM --> FAIL
12:00 PM should be 1:30 AM
Adding 30 minutes to 1240 PM --> FAIL
12:00 PM should be 1:10 AM
Adding 90 minutes to 1240 PM --> FAIL
12:00 PM should be 2:10 AM
Adding 11 minutes to 1150 PM --> FAIL
12:00 PM should be 12:01 AM
Adding 4321 minutes to 1150 PM --> FAIL
12:00 PM should be 11:51 PM
```

Ultimately if the program was working as its should, they would all evaluate to  PASS. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `Time.addMinutes(int)` seems to just return a blank `Time` object (0,0)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your existing `fixMe` method is supposed to work, but here is a working implementation:

```
private void fixMe() {
    hours += minutes / 60;
    minutes %= 60;
    if (minutes < 0) { // if minutes was negative,
        minutes += 60; // correct the result of the modulus 60 to make it positive
        hours--;       // correct the result of the /60 by subtracting one more hour
    }
    hours %= 24;
    if (hours < 0) { // if hours was negative,
        hours += 24; // correct the modulus 24 to be positive
    }
}
```

This basically just does modulus/integer division to get the values into the correct ranges. The trick is handling negative inputs; in those cases, the modulus will be negative, and the result of integer division will be one more than you want. Correct for those factors, and it works as intended.

Also, make sure that your `addMinutes(int)` method actually adds minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the math a lot simpler (and consequently less error prone) by representing all times as seconds internally in your class, and only converting this internal representation to hours and minutes when necessary. That way, your `addMinutes()` method only needs to do simple addition:

```
public void addMinutes(int m) {
    this.seconds += m * 60;
}
```

The `getHour()` and `getMinute()` methods would need to do some simple math to figure out the correct hour and minute, but on the other hand you could then extend your class with methods to get the day, month, year and second as well.

In fact a common way of implementing time and date formats in programming is to store the number of seconds passed since a specific point in time. If you're interested you can [read more about that here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)#Computing).

Also, you might want to check out the existing [Java date and time APIs](https://dzone.com/articles/deeper-look-java-8-date-and).